# Checking objects for identity and Sonar issues

Tags: java, object, sonarqube, identity

We are checking the quality of our code using Sonar, and Sonar found code which compares objects for identity like this:

```
if (cellOfInterest == currentCell) { … }
```

Sonar finds this kind of identity check peculiar enough to call it critical and proposes to replace the identity check (using `==`) with a check for equality (using `.equals()` instead).  Identity checks, so the rationale behind this, are often not what is meant.

In our case, however, we iterate through a list of `Cell`s and check in each iteration (`currentCell`) whether we are handling a special cell we already have (`cellOfInterest`).

I'd like to hear if there are other patterns than ours which are common and which avoid this issue simply by using a different design.  Or what solutions do you propose to avoid using an identity check in the mentioned situation?

We considered a replacement of the identity check with an equality check as described above but it does not seem applicable in our situation because other cells might be "equal" as well but not identical.

All ideas are welcome!

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please comment in such cases!  I have no idea on how to improve my question without you telling me what made you downvote.

Comment: Are all these cells of a certain class?

Comment: Let's say yes and let's also split the question in two parts, once we say that class comes from a 3rd party library, so it cannot be touched; and once we say it's our own class and can be changed.

Comment: If you really want to check for identical objects then I neither see another way nor a reason to change it. After all, that's what the `==` operator is made for. Maybe it would help to see some of the "surrounding" code or have a more detailed explanation of your use case to come up with a completely different approach.

Answer (score 7):

If identity is what you need then it is what you need. The warning makes sense as it is often a bug but in this case it's not.

As an example, [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) (which works with identity vs. equality) has this in its javadoc:

> This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! [...] ***This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.***

So it is rarely useful but has its uses. You are in a similar position. And of course, [its internal code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/IdentityHashMap.java?av=f#304) does exactly what you expect, it uses `==` to get a key.

Bottom line: I don't see why you would need to make the code more complex just because some static code analysis tool says it may be a problem - such a tool is supposed to help you, not to force you into some weird construct that will essentially do the same thing. I would explain why `==` is used in a comment for clarity, mark it as a false positive and move on.

If you really want to remove the warning, the only option I can think of is to use `equals` and change the `equals` method to either:

- the default `Object#equals` which is based on identity
- some implementation that uniquely identifies the cells, maybe based on some unique id or coordinates?

Comment: Is there a way to call `Object.equals()` for two instances?  Can I retrieve the address of an instance to compare these?  (That would implement an identity check effectively and probably be explicit enough for Sonar not to complain.)

Comment: @Alfe (1) You would need to remove the `equals` method from your Cell class to inherit the default behaviour - if you need an `equals` method for other purposes then I don't think there is a way. (2) You could use `System.identityHashCode` but collisions are possible - so not an option. In the end, the language has a specific operator for your purpose, it's `==` and any workaround will consist in hiding the use of `==` to Sonar but will use it somewhere... For example you could add a `static isIdentical (Cell c1, Cell c2) { return c1 == c2; }` but sonar will probably complain about it too...

Answer (score 2):

For Strings and most other Java objects, it is possible to have 2 instances which are identity unequal but are actually equivalent by `.equals`. It's conventional to avoid `==` for comparison (using equals or compareTo instead) but if it works, it works. You can mark the item as a false positive in SonarQube.

Comment: Hm, no, I would not agree with the attitude that it working means it's a false positive.  Code can work perfectly and be flawed nevertheless.  The drawbacks of some implementations only show up when the code is maintained or extended etc.

Answer (score 1):

At first you will not run into problems if you just replace your identity check with an equals call (except that you will have to check for null values on cellOfInterest), as the default implementation of equals in Object is the identity check.

```
if (cellOfInterest != null && cellOfInterest.equals(currentCell)) { … }
```

will not break the code. It behaves exactly the same way as your code, when I may suppose that currentCell will not be null.

To omit the null check (and retain the behaviour on both values being null) you can also use (since Java 7)

```
if(Objects.equals(cellOfInterest, currentCell)) { ...}
```

In general using equals is the better architecture.

To view both cases you mentioned:

- If the class is changeable by yourself, you might (or might not) come to the conclusion that there are better ways for equality than identity; so you just change the equals (and do not forget the hashCode!) in your class.
- If you cannot change the class, you have to trust in a meaningful implementation  of equals and hashCode by the provider of the class.

Comment: For these `Cell`s instances, I would assume that two empty cells, being not identical, would still be considered equal, so any `.equals()` special to these `Cell`s should implement this.  In this case using `.equals()` would break our code.

Comment: No, equals will exist, as every object in Java extends Object, which implements it by using identity.

Comment: Parts of your answer sound like I could be interested in a comparison of two objects for being *alike* (that's what `equals()` means).  But I'm *only* interested in an identity check.  Nothing else will solve my problem (unless maybe a completely different approach which avoids comparisons altogether).  I only look for ways to *express* that identity check in a way so that Sonar accepts it, probably because it is way more explicit than the simple `==` operator.

Comment: This is your current requirement. As you know, requirements may change. And still, using equals is the recommended Java way. This is what either Sonar and me are trying to tell you... ;)

Comment: Sorry, no you don't recommend using `==` but `.equals()`.  I got that one wrong (I removed that comment and propose to remove these two as well).

Comment: Recommending to use `.equals()` instead of `==` effectively means recommending not to check the identity of instances.  This may be a good idea (but I don't yet understand why).  But it leaves the open question how to perform the task of iterating through a list of instances and perform a special handling of a pre-known instance.